Maximally Entangled Non-Bell Forms in Two Qubits
Is it possible to have Maximally Entangled states( von Neumann entropy close to 1) but they are not actually bell states? Google Ai responses 'yes' but I could not find research articles.

I'll give a general answer that goes beyond two-qubits. Let $|\psi\rangle_{AB}$ be a pure bipartite state and let $d = \min\{\mathrm{dim}(A), \mathrm{dim}(B)\}$. Then the Schmidt decomposition says that there exists an orthonormal basis $\{|v_i\rangle_A\}_i$ for $A$, an orthonormal basis $\{|w_j\rangle\}_{j}$ for system $B$ and $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=0}^{d-1} \geq 0$ satisfying $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$ such that
$$
|\psi\rangle_{AB} = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \sqrt{\lambda_i} |v_i\rangle_A \otimes |w_i\rangle_B\,.
$$
In other words, for any pure bipartite state, there always exists a choice of basis such that the state looks nice and symmetric across the bipartition.
Now, the Schmidt decomposition implies that the reduced states have the same eigenvalues (namely $\{\lambda_i\}_i$) and this further implies that $H(A) = H(B) = -\sum_i \lambda_i \log \lambda_i$. We thus have that the entropies of the subsystems is maximal if $\lambda_i = \frac{1}{d}$ for all $i$. This leads to the following conclusion, a state is called maximally entangled there exist local orthonormal bases such that it takes the form
$$
|\psi\rangle_{AB} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} |v_i\rangle_A \otimes |w_j \rangle_B.
$$
But as all orthonormal bases can be related by a unitary transformation we find that all maximally entangled states are of the form
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}(U_A \otimes U_B) \sum_{j=0}^{d-1}|jj\rangle_{AB}
$$
where $U_A$ is any unitary on $A$ and $U_B$ is any unitary on $B$.
For the two-qubit case you therefore have that all maximally entangled states look like
$$
(U_A \otimes U_B) \frac{|00\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$

First off, your criterion to define a maximally entangled state seems incorrect. The von Neumann entropy of a maximally-entangled bipartite state is not 1, but it is rather the von Neumann entropy of each of the substates that compose it.
That being said, any state of the form:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|00\rangle + e^{i \theta}|11\rangle \right) \; \text{or} \; \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|01\rangle + e^{i \theta} |10\rangle \right), \; \text{such that: } \theta \notin \{0,\pi\} $$
is technically a maximally-entangled two-qubit state that is not a Bell state.

To clarify, Entropy Value of 1 for each qubit indicates maximal entanglement and Lower than 1 means not maximally entangled(0 : separable), am I right?

that's correct.
